# How to clone array of object by value and not by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having trouble to copy an array of objects using Lodash.

Please see the code,

```
var freshSlots = _.clone(this.bookingSlots);
console.log(freshSlots) // It prints the new changed copy
this.bookingSlots=this.bookingSlots[0].booked=true // here I am running some loops and changing the property values of this.bookingSlots
```

As you can see, this cloning is happening by reference that's why I never get the old copy. How can I get the old copy by values?

Thank you.

Comment: As the [Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#clone) say `_.clone` "Creates a shallow clone of a value". Use `_.cloneDeep` instead.

Comment: Thank you. :) it works. You can post this as an answer